# ¿Cómo obtener un mapa desde Neo4J en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j

Utilizando la siguiente query en Cypher, me devuelve algo que se parece a una lista de mapas:

```
Query: "MATCH (t:Tweet) with t.lang as lkey, count(t) as lvalue return apoc.map.fromValues([lkey,lvalue])"
Output: { "en" : 2000 }, { "ar" : 1300 }
```

Empleando py2neo para hacer peticiones a la base de datos, cuando evalúo la sentencia anterior, sólo me devuelve el primer elemento, { "en" : 2000 }, en vez de devolverme una lista de mapas, [{ "en" : 2000 },  { "ar" : 1300 }]

Empleo el siguiente método en python

```
def get_connection():
    g = Graph(host='localhost', user={user}, password={password})
    return g

def group_by_languages():
    sentence = "MATCH (t:Tweet) with t.lang as lkey, count(t) as lvalue return 
apoc.map.fromValues([lkey,lvalue])"
    graph = get_connection()
    return graph.evaluate(sentence)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo conseguí, así que dejo la solución para alguien que lo necesite:

Al final utilicé la query anterior (recordad instalar el paquete APOC):

```
MATCH (t:Tweet) with t.lang as lkey, count(t) as lvalue return apoc.map.fromValues([lkey,lvalue])
```

Esta query devolver un Result, objeto que no es compatible con Python pero se puede obtener los valores de la siguiente forma:

```
result = graph.run(sentence)

aux_map = dict()
for l in result:
    aux_map.update(l.values()[0])
```

Combinando todo, se puede crear una función en Python que te devuelva un diccionario desde Neo4j:

```
def group_by_languages():
    sentence = "MATCH (t:Tweet) with t.lang as lkey, count(t) as lvalue return apoc.map.fromValues([lkey,lvalue])"
    graph = get_connection()
    result = graph.run(sentence)

    aux_map = dict()
    for l in result:
        aux_map.update(l.values()[0])

    return aux_map
```